# Express/Nodejs :Request Entity Too Large On Plesk

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer, plesk

I am trying to upload file using nodejs & multer.
I am using plesk server and it work probably on my local host but when I trying upload file on server (plesk) I got the 413(Request Entity Too Large).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

upload file how size? you can enlarge upload size
However, it is not recommended to be too large

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).